# Проблема с загрузкой сцены

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: Иерархия главного меню]

у меня проблема которую я пока не в силах решить.

У меня есть две сцены главное меню (меню) и игровая сцена (игра), также в игре присутствует инвентарь и предметы меняющие хар-ки.
Если я начинаю игру в главном меню и потом перехожу в игровую сцену, то все работает (меню -> игра). Если я из игровой сцены перейду в нее снова (перезапущу ее), то все также будет функционировать (игра -> игра).

Но вот если я из игровой сцены перейду в меню и потом в игровую сцену (игра -> меню -> игра), то все ломается. Предметы с пола не подбираются, при нажатии на кнопки в инвентаре выходит ошибка. Обе ошибки примерно одинаковы:

1. При попытке подбора предмета выходит ошибка (MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Image' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.)
2. При нажатии на кнопки в инвентаре ошибка (MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.)

Не понимаю в чем дело, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Этл конечно не решит проблему, но как по мне, UI можно поверх сцены рисовать, а не выделять под него отдельную сцену.

Comment: Хочу чтобы можно было продолжить игру по кнопке Continue и была загрузка на переходе в нужную сцену, для этого  решил сделать отдельную сцену под главное меню

Comment: Игру модно запаузить не меняя сцены

Comment: у меня уже есть такая функция, из нее я как раз и выхожу в главное меню

Answer (score 1):

Эти ошибки возникают из-за того, что при переходе из меню в игровую сцену некоторые объекты не были пересозданы. Чтобы решить эту проблему, вам нужно перезагрузить игровую сцену и пересоздать все необходимые объекты при переходе из меню в игровую сцену. Вы можете это сделать, используя функцию `SceneManager.LoadScene()` или используя систему перезагрузки сцены в вашей игре.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но мне не помогло :( 
Я перед загрузкой главного меню поставил загрузку сцены игры (игра -> игра -> меню -> игра), но ошибка все еще есть...
После Вашего совета я решил в главном меню перезапустить эту сцену (меню -> меню -> игра) и все тоже сломалось, хотя сразу из меню в игру все работает отлично.
Я думаю что теряются префабы, хотя они бы сразу пропадали после перехода из сцены